# jquery dynamic function

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I just need the logic and understanding on how I can do this.

The problem:

I have several functions that are very similar but I want to create/call the dynamically

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {         
    function foo() {
        $("#foo_elem").toggle(true).attr('required', true);
        alert('This is foo');
    }

    function bar() {
        $("#bar_elem").toggle(true).attr('required', true);
        alert('This is bar');
    }
});
```

How can I pass in foo/bar to create the function? Pseudo code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // would pass foo/bar to this?        
    $($x)(function() {
        $("#"+$(this)+"_elem").toggle(true).attr('required', true);
        alert('This is '+$(this));
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe your example doesn't cover the extend of your problem, but can't you just use one method with an argument?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to dynamically call foo or bar?

```
function callMethod(method)
{
     method();
}

callMethod(foo); // foo is the symbol for your method
callMethod(bar); // etc
```

At a high level. In your instance, though, you're asking to use that symbol as just a variable in your selector:

```
function callMethod(elementPrefix)
{
    $('#' + elementPrefix+ '_elem').toggle(true).attr('required', true);
    alert('This is ' + elementPrefix);
}
```

If you want to use it both as a string value, and the method name, you can eval the symbol to get the method:

```
var methodName = 'foo';
var text = 'This is ' + methodName; // This is foo
var method = eval('(' + methodName + ')');
method(); // calls foo()
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I understood your question fully, but do you want to dynamically create a function based on some arguments? If so, you could do something like this:

```
function make_func(x) {
  return function() {
    $("#"+x+"_elem").toggle(true).attr('required', true);
    alert('This is '+x);
  };
}
```

Then `make_func('foo')` would return a function which is equivalent to the function `foo` in your original example.